# Unable to initialize a DB cluster and if initialized, pg_ctl does recognize active PostgreSQL services?

Tags: postgresql, clustering, psql, debian

I am running **Debian@11.6** via `wsl2` on Windows 11.

I got a few issues.

> One - **I am unable to initialize a PostgreSQL DB cluster**

Below are my bash configurations that I edited using `sudo nano`.

**~/.bashrc and ~/.profile**

```shell
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin
export PATH
export PGDATA="/usr/local/pgsql/data"
```

Everything works fine. But, when I execute `initdb -D PGDATA`, **PGDATA folder is created in `/home/user/` directory** which is not recognized by some of PostgreSQL commands.

So as an alternative, I deleted the **~/PGDATA** and tried `pg_createcluster -d PGDATA`, which returns me the output shown below -

```shell
Usage: /usr/bin/pg_createcluster [options] <version> <cluster name> [-- <initdb options>]

Options:
  -u <uid>      cluster owner and superuser (default: 'postgres')
  -g <gid>      group for data files (default: primary group of owner)
  -d <dir>      data directory (default:
                /var/lib/postgresql/<version>/<cluster name>)
  -s <dir>      socket directory (default: /var/run/postgresql for clusters
                owned by 'postgres', /tmp for other clusters)
  -l <dir>      path to desired log file (default:
                /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-<version>-<cluster>.log)
  --locale <encoding>
                set cluster locale (default: inherit from environment)
  --lc-collate/ctype/messages/monetary/numeric/time <locale>
                like --locale, but only set for a particular category
  -e <encoding> Default encoding (default: derived from locale)
  -p <port>     port number (default: next free port starting from 5432)
  --start       start the cluster after creating it
  --start-conf auto|manual|disabled
                Set automatic startup behaviour in start.conf (default: 'auto')
  --createclusterconf=file alternative createcluster.conf to use
  --environment=file alternative environment file to use
  <initdb options> other options to pass to initdb
```

That is, I cannot create a cluster using `pg_createcluster` and the one I created using `initdb` isn't recognized by some of the PostgreSQL commands. And oh, by the way, when I `initdb` as superuser, a new issue is thrown at my face as shown below or may be, I am short on knowledge about `initdb`.

```shell
initdb: error: cannot be run as root
initdb: hint: Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will own the server process.
```

> Two - I have configured the **pg_ident.conf** in the above created **PGDATA** folder yet I get the error below for `psql -U postgres`

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres".
```

Below is my `pg_ident.conf`.

```shell
# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------

# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
suMAP           myUserName              postgresql
```

> Three - `pg_ctl` is not recognizing the active POSTGRESQL services.

`pg_ctl reload` returns the output shown below.

```shell
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.
```

`sudo systemctl status postgre*` shows two active psotgresql service as shown below.

```shell
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2023-01-08 19:04:36 GMT; 25min ago
    Process: 359 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 359 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 08 19:04:36 Unfuckwithable systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jan 08 19:04:36 Unfuckwithable systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.

● postgresql@15-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 15-main
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-01-08 19:04:44 GMT; 25min ago
    Process: 366 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 15-main start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 371 (postgres)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 9347)
     Memory: 18.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@15-main.service
             ├─371 /usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/15/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf
             ├─372 postgres: 15/main: checkpointer
             ├─373 postgres: 15/main: background writer
             ├─375 postgres: 15/main: walwriter
             ├─376 postgres: 15/main: autovacuum launcher
             └─377 postgres: 15/main: logical replication launcher

Jan 08 19:04:42 Unfuckwithable systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 15-main...
Jan 08 19:04:44 Unfuckwithable systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL Cluster 15-main.
```

I am unable to comprehend what exactly is going on, can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: You should reference environment variables (such as `PGDATA` set in the profile) using `$`, e.g. `initdb -D $PGDATA`. You should probably spend some time studying Bash command syntax if you intend to use the shell.